# Wobble in steering (not tyre)?

Tags: steering, cv-boot

I have a '94 4th gen Honda Prelude. Driving home today I felt a distinct wobble through the steering wheel. I immediately thought I had a flat and pulled over but found the tyre is fine.

The wobble seems to get worse when cornering and is barely noticeable on straights.

Would anyone know what could be causing this? CV joint?

Comment: could be bearings or wheel balance perhaps?

Comment: I would lean towards wheel bearing.

Comment: Can you actually feel a worn wheel bearing through the steering wheel?

Comment: Could be tracking/alignment?

Answer (score 1):

Could also be upper or lower control arms from the sounds of it, before this started to happen did you hear or notice anything else?  maybe a popping sound around corners?  Bearings will make noise when going around a corner if they are wearing out.

Also I know some Preludes from this era had 4 wheel steering,  does yours have this option?  If so this could be the cause of your troubles, as it was a passive 4 wheel steering system.  and Although it was more robust than the Super HI-CAS system found in Nissan's of the same era, it can cause vibrations if it is not in proper working order.

Comment: Yes, I heard a cracking/popping noise going around corners. I assumed it was the CV joins. Yes it has the 4WS

Comment: Sounds like ball joints to me (popping sound around corners), this is easy to check and often ball joints wear out when dealing with oldish vehicles.  I would get this looked into ASAP, if it is a ball joint and it totally fails and snaps at speed, your car will go out of control, which will not be a good time. I highly suggest you get the 4WS system looked at. The bushings tend to rot away over time as they are not urethane and this can lead to the issue you described as the system is only doing something when you go around corners.